# Trouble assigning output variable from awscli task in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, aws-cli

When I run the following task in azure devops, the task will output an ImageId variable, I am having trouble taking the output and assigning it to a variable in the pipeline.

```
  - task: AWSCLI@1    
    name: "getAMI"
    inputs:    
      awsCredentials: 'AWS Service connection'
      regionName: 'us-east-2'
      awsCommand: 'ec2'
      awsSubCommand: 'copy-image'
      awsArguments: '--region us-east-2 --source-region us-east-2 --name Test-AMI-Copy --source-image-id ami-0d8400xx190cfxxxx --description "this is a test copy"' 
      outputVariable: 'ImageId'
```

I have tried:

```
  - bash: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ImageId;isOutput=true]$(ImageId)"
    displayName: 'Set stage output variables'
    name: setOutputs
```

```
  - bash: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ImageId;isOutput=true]$(getAMI.ImageId)"
    displayName: 'Set stage output variables'
    name: setOutputs
```

How do you grab the output of the last task and assign it to a variable properly? I have searched for a few hours and only see examples of tasks that are inline scripts, not an awscli@2 task.